# Futuro do Eclipse para desenvolvimento Android

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Quais são os impactos do Google não dar mais suporte ao Eclipse? Ainda poderei utilizar a ferramenta para criar aplicações Android?

Comment: Migrei para o AS tem 1 mês a IDE tem muitas funcionalidades legais, porém é muito mais pesado que o eclipse, tenho problemas constantes onde ele trava isso rodando em uma maquina I5, 4 gb ram e video off.

Comment: Isto é verdade...tive que por 8 GB de RAM aqui pra aguentar o AS. Sem contar a velocidade de debug e compile...mas o cabo não ajuda, então...hehe

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho, eu já vou fazer esse upgrade no meu notebook kkk, na empresa uso 8gb em casa apenas 4

Comment: Ah kkk hoje em dia sem chance, 8 GB e olhe lá...SSD também é outraaa coisa. Mas enfim! Abraçoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, podes continuar a utilizar. Basicamente significa que não haverá mais updates ao plugin Android Development Tools (ADT) depois do final do ano. Não vais poder tirar partido de novas versões e funcionalidades.

Até lá, vai te adaptando ao Android Studio ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Até o final deste ano (2015)**, o Google vai manter o suporte ao Eclipse.

Eu recomendaria de antemão efetuar a migração usando a [ferramenta de migração](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) deles e acredite, não é difícil.

O post oficial do blog informou que os usuários que ainda não migraram para o `Android Studio`, esta é a hora. Os desenvolvedores terão os projetos completamente compatíveis com o `Android Studio` ([ferramenta de migração](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)).

> "To that end and to focus all of our efforts on making Android Studio
>   better and faster, we are ending development and official support for
>   the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of the year.
>   This specifically includes the Eclipse ADT plugin and Android Ant
>   build system"